# How to highlight points on MapBox api

Tags: javascript, spring-boot, thymeleaf, mapbox

I am a new software developer. I am doing a demo project for work. We are working with Spring Boot and Thymeleaf. At the moment I have a program that will generate a map with a route. The route has a start, middle and end location. The locations are given by the user. When the locations are hard coded in they are highlighted on the map with coloured dots. However, when the locations are given by the user the dots do not show up. It would mean a lot to me if someone could help me with this. Thanks!

This is the javascript script for generating the MapBox map

```
<script th:inline="javascript">
    mapboxgl.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1IjoiamVzc2ljYWhvZXkiLCJhIjoiY2xvcGt6ODYzMGJvazJxbzZzMW9qMmppaiJ9.nmUH756QkkjG05Wk9CzN6A';
    const map = new mapboxgl.Map({
        container: 'map',
        style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v12',
        center: [-7.900717096503491, 53.416140937630736], // starting position
        zoom: 12
    });


    const start = [[${locations.start}]];
    const middle = [[${locations.option}]];
    const end = [[${locations.end}]];


    // Create a function to make a directions request
    async function getRoute(coordinates) {
        // Make a directions request using driving profile
        const query = await fetch(
            `https://api.mapbox.com/directions/v5/mapbox/driving/${coordinates.join(';')}?steps=true&geometries=geojson&access_token=${mapboxgl.accessToken}`,
            { method: 'GET' }
        );
        const json = await query.json();
        const data = json.routes[0];
        const route = data.geometry.coordinates;
        const geojson = {
            type: 'Feature',
            properties: {},
            geometry: {
                type: 'LineString',
                coordinates: route
            }
        };

        // If the route already exists on the map, reset it using setData
        if (map.getSource('route')) {
            map.getSource('route').setData(geojson);
        } else {
            // Otherwise, make a new request
            map.addLayer({
                id: 'route',
                type: 'line',
                source: {
                    type: 'geojson',
                    data: geojson
                },
                layout: {
                    'line-join': 'round',
                    'line-cap': 'round'
                },
                paint: {
                    'line-color': '#3887be',
                    'line-width': 5,
                    'line-opacity': 0.75
                }
            });
        }
    }

    map.on('load', () => {
        // Make an initial directions request for the entire route
        getRoute([start, middle, end]);

        // Add starting, middle, and ending points to the map
        map.addLayer({
            id: 'start',
            type: 'circle',
            source: {
                type: 'geojson',
                data: {
                    type: 'FeatureCollection',
                    features: [
                        {
                            type: 'Feature',
                            properties: {},
                            geometry: {
                                type: 'Point',
                                coordinates: start
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            paint: {
                'circle-radius': 10,
                'circle-color': '#3887be'
            }
        });

        map.addLayer({
            id: 'middle',
            type: 'circle',
            source: {
                type: 'geojson',
                data: {
                    type: 'FeatureCollection',
                    features: [
                        {
                            type: 'Feature',
                            properties: {},
                            geometry: {
                                type: 'Point',
                                coordinates: middle
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            paint: {
                'circle-radius': 100,
                'circle-color': '#ff5733'
            }
        });

        map.addLayer({
            id: 'end',
            type: 'circle',
            source: {
                type: 'geojson',
                data: {
                    type: 'FeatureCollection',
                    features: [
                        {
                            type: 'Feature',
                            properties: {},
                            geometry: {
                                type: 'Point',
                                coordinates: end
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            paint: {
                'circle-radius': 10,
                'circle-color': '#f30'
            }
        });


        // Handle map click to set a new route
        map.on('click', (event) => {
            const clickedCoordinates = Object.keys(event.lngLat).map((key) => event.lngLat[key]);
            getRoute([start, middle, clickedCoordinates]);
        });
    });

</script>
```

Comment: If you want help, more effort into a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would really help.  What does the code look like when it works, and what does the Thymeleaf output? There is both too much, and not enough information here...